# Mac shell command

Tags: bash

I'm the one who never use bash before, could anyone told me how to combine those two command. (And only open the game once)

Change the language and open the game.

```
open /Applications/League\ of\ Legends.app --args --locale=zh_CN
```

Add the voice chat and open the game.

```
cd '/Applications/League of Legends.app/Contents/LoL/'
./LeagueClient.app/Contents/MacOS/LeagueClient
```

appreciate for any help

Comment: Please show output of `echo "$ZSH_VERSION:$BASH_VERSION"`.

Comment: And also the output of `env | grep LANG`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use && in csh, zsh, and bash.

```
open /Applications/League\ of\ Legends.app --args --locale=zh_CN && (cd '/Applications/League of Legends.app/Contents/LoL/'; ./LeagueClient.app/Contents/MacOS/LeagueClient)
```

Alternatively, you can create a script:

```
% mkdir ~/bin
mkdir: /Users/risner/bin: File exists
% touch ~/bin/lol.sh
% open -e ~/bin/lol.sh
% chmod +x ~/bin/lol.sh
```

The **%** represents the command prompt from you shell.

Then put this inside the file opened by TextEdit:

```
#!/bin/sh
open /Applications/League\ of\ Legends.app --args --locale=zh_CN && \
    ( \
        cd '/Applications/League of Legends.app/Contents/LoL/'; \
        ./LeagueClient.app/Contents/MacOS/LeagueClient \
    )
```

The script opens the application passing the locale setting to your application. Then if that succeeded, open the League client.